# Capture output audio spectrum in Python

Tags: python, gstreamer, audio-recording

## The challenge

To capture the spectrum of the output audio.

## 1st attempt

```
import gtk, gst

def playerbin_message(bus, message):
    if message.type == gst.MESSAGE_ELEMENT:
        struct = message.structure
        if struct.get_name() == 'spectrum':
            print struct['magnitude']
pipeline = gst.parse_launch(
    'pulsesrc device="alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor" ! spectrum ! fakesink')
bus = pipeline.get_bus()
bus.add_signal_watch()
bus.connect('message', playerbin_message)
pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)
gtk.main()
```

### Where does it fail?

From some reason, the script work only sometimes. Usually it won't print anything.

@otopolsky found in verbose mode log the following line:

```
INFO spectrum gstspectrum.c:1051:gst_spectrum_transform_ip:<spectrum0> interval 0:00:00.100000000, fpi 4410, error 0:00:00.000000000
```

## 2nd attempt

As @otopolsky adviced, I tried running:

```
GST_DEBUG=4,spectrum:7 gst-launch-0.10 pulsesrc device="alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor" ! spectrum ! fakesink > out.log
```

And got [this output](http://pastebin.com/eEaW06VT).

This get **stuck**:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v -m pulsesrc device="alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor" ! spectrum ! fakesink
```

While this **works**:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -m pulsesrc device="alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor" ! spectrum ! fakesink
```

(only the version was changed).

## 3rd attempt

Moved to python gi:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst

GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)

def handler(bus, msg):
    if msg.type == Gst.MessageType.ELEMENT:
        struct = msg.get_structure()
        print struct.get_value('magnitude')

p = Gst.parse_launch(
    'pulsesrc device="alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor" ! spectrum ! fakesink')

bus = p.get_bus()
bus.add_signal_watch()
bus.connect('message', handler)
p.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

ctx = GObject.main_context_default()
while ctx:
    ctx.iteration()
```

### Where does it fail?

```
TypeError: unknown type GstValueList
```

## The questions

- How can the scripts be fixed to work on every execution?
- Is there another way to capture output spectrum using Python?

Comment: what about adding `export GST_DEBUG=3` (or 4) before executing the python script?

Comment: Successful log: http://pastebin.com/5nBypmtv
, unsuccessful log: http://pastebin.com/pCfzAfCe

Comment: ok what about trying gstreamer 1.2 ? the scenario 2 - did it worked or it all the time finished after some time? what about using `alsasrc` (I am not sure if it was accesible in gst 0.10.x)?

Comment: @otopolsky I've added the results of scenario 2.
`alsasrc` is accesible in gst 0.10, do you know how I can use it to capture the internal sound instead of the microphone?

Comment: added alsasrc example to answer

Answer (score 1):

You are using 0.10.36 .. quite old.. can you not use newer gstreamer, say 1.2?

you are running Ubuntu so it should not be a problem.. the 0.10.x and 1.2 can easily coexist beside each other.. I dont know if its ok with your python bindings..

This may be the problematic line (from your pastebin, please add that part into your question..)

`INFO spectrum gstspectrum.c:1051:gst_spectrum_transform_ip:<spectrum0> interval 0:00:00.100000000, fpi 4410, error 0:00:00.000000000`

This is the source [code](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good/tree/gst/spectrum/gstspectrum.c?h=0.10#n1048).. 
It says something about rounding error and uninitialized FFT:

> /* If we don't have a FFT context yet (or it was reset due to
>   parameter    * changes) get one and allocate memory for everything
>   */
>
> /* number of sample frames we process before posting a message
>   * interval is in ns */
>
> /* rounding error for frames_per_interval in ns,
>   * aggregated it in accumulated_error */

you can run again to get more details with:

`export GST_DEBUG=4,spectrum:7`

Can you run the pipe in gst-launch?

`GST_DEBUG=4,spectrum:7 gst-launch-0.10 pulsesrc device="alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor" ! spectrum ! fakesink`

UPDATE:

Try with alsasrc if you hear it.. (autoaudiosink or alsasink):

```
gst-launch-1.0 alsasrc device=hw:0,2 ! spectrum ! autoaudiosink
```

`hw:X,Y` format explanation: `X = card number, Y = device name`

Getting it from `arecord -l` for input devices like microphone etc..

and `aplay -l` for output devices..

```
> arecord -l | grep card
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: ALC887-VD Alt Analog [ALC887-VD Alt Analog]
```

Comment: executing `$ arecord -l | grep card` gives `card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: 92HD87B1/3 Analog [92HD87B1/3 Analog]` and only `hw:0,0` works. But it gives only the microphone.

Comment: ok @Michael and does the microphone work with spectrum when you use this alsasrc pipe in your code?

Comment: yes, alsasrc pipe in python using gst-0.10 does produce spectrum `gst.parse_launch('alsasrc device=hw:0,0 ! spectrum ! fakesink')`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `GstValueList` is not supported by gst-python.

There is an inelegant way to get data from the `GstValueList`. We can convert the message structure into a string, then convert the string to a float array.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst
import re

GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)


def on_message(bus, msg):
    struct = msg.get_structure()
    if struct.get_name() == 'spectrum':
        struct_str = struct.to_string()
        magnitude_str = re.match(r'.*magnitude=\(float\){(.*)}.*', struct_str)
        if magnitude_str:
            magnitude = map(float, magnitude_str.group(1).split(','))
            print magnitude

pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(
    'audiotestsrc ! spectrum interval=1000000000 bands=16 post-messages=true message-magnitude=1 ! directsoundsink'
)

bus = pipeline.get_bus()
bus.add_signal_watch()
bus.connect('message::element', on_message)

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

loop = GObject.MainLoop()
loop.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Realising this question is very old (but helpful!), but...

I had the same problem and figured out it was just a matter of using the [`get_list()`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gststructure.html?gi-language=python#gst_structure_get_list) binding not `get_value()`. This gives you a boolean and and a`GObject.ValueArray` which seems usable:

```
struct = msg.get_structure()
success, values = struct.get_list("magnitude")
if struct.get_name() == "spectrum":
    mags = [values.get_nth(i) for i in range(values.n_values)]
```